# Angular app routing errors when testing production build

Tags: angular, build, prototype, production

Testing my apps production build with `ng build --prod` and `ng serve --prod` I get these errors on chrome:

[image: Google Chrome console errors]

Firefox gives a bit different output in the console:

[image: Firefox console errors]

Any ideas what can cause it? I'm running angular 8.

Then testing app with simple ng serve everything looks fine, no errors in the console only after production. Errors remain then app is hosted in server as well. Tell if I need to give more info about my app.

This is my app.routing.ts file:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FrontendPanelLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(mod => mod.PagesModule)
  }
];
```

and pages.routing.ts:

```
export const PagesRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: pages.Home,
    component: LandingComponent
  },
  {
    path: pages.Products,
    component: ProductsComponent
  },
  {
    path: pages.Products + '/:category',
    component: ProductsListComponent
  },
  {
    path: pages.Products + '/:category/:product',
    component: ProductsViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: pages.Services,
    component: ServicesComponent
  },
  {
    path: pages.Services + '/:service',
    component: ProductsViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: pages.About,
    component: AboutUsComponent
  },
  {
    path: pages.Contacts,
    component: ContactsComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: pages.Home
  }
];
```

this is a cause of the errors but its in node_modules router.js file not my code. Strange why these error only appear after `ng build --prod`, `ng serve` does not show any problems.

```
function defaultUrlMatcher(segments, segmentGroup, route) {
    var parts = route.path.split('/');
    if (parts.length > segments.length) {
        // The actual URL is shorter than the config, no match
        return null;
    }
    if (route.pathMatch === 'full' &&
        (segmentGroup.hasChildren() || parts.length < segments.length)) {
        // The config is longer than the actual URL but we are looking for a full match, return null
        return null;
    }
    var posParams = {};
    // Check each config part against the actual URL
    for (var index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
        var part = parts[index];
        var segment = segments[index];
        var isParameter = part.startsWith(':');
        if (isParameter) {
            posParams[part.substring(1)] = segment;
        }
        else if (part !== segment.path) {
            // The actual URL part does not match the config, no match
            return null;
        }
    }
    return { consumed: segments.slice(0, parts.length), posParams: posParams };
}
```

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek yes, but router.js.pre-build-optimizer is from node-modules, is this a problem with module itself?

Comment: Hi there @Cooper. Please share your app route files. It looks like something is going wrong there.

Comment: @DamianC updated!

Comment: You could change to the new syntax for lazy loaded routes: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: @DamianC updated the app.routing.ts to lazy load but errors stays, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, the problem was not in router.js file but in my routing file. I just changed all the path with simple strings without references and it is working right now. Thank you.

```
export const PagesRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: LandingComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products/:category',
    component: ProductsListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products/:category/:product',
    component: ProductsViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'services',
    component: ServicesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'services/:service',
    component: ProductsViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutUsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'contacts',
    component: ContactsComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: pages.Home
  }
];
```

Comment: this is a snag I've hit with angular routing in AoT as well. I had to eliminate all references to values from modules or namespaces from my routing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue when I was trying to build for production. My issue was the same, I was using some other files(app-route.constant.ts) to maintain routes and then referring that file to app-routing.module.ts. It seems to be not working.

app-route.contant.ts

```
const path ={
  paths: {
accessDenied: `access-denied`,
leadershipstacked: {
  path: `leadership-stacked`,
  routeChildren: {},
},}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: `${appRoute.path.leadershipstacked}`,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./leadership/leadership.module').then((m) => m.LeadershipModule),
  }
]
```

Then I tried directly mentioning the path in the app-routing.module.ts file and it is working fine.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    
      {
        path: 'PMO/:projectID/leadership',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./leadership/leadership.module').then((m) => m.LeadershipModule),
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very obvious for me. Did you read that error message? There should be something you want to split but it does not exists -> undefined. Like if you want to delete from an array what is not defined.
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.... Focus this and read the messages man. Don't panic, don't run. Slowly. Check that string or whatever you want to split.

Comment: I understand that but it bugs me that its from node-modules not code that I wrote.

Comment: Oh. Ookay. Just tried to help. It's interesting then.

Comment: Sure the issue is being emitted from router.js which I'm 99% sure is from the framework, but it's probably happening due to misconfiguration of the project or the routes.  Only way to dig further is to find out what it's trying to do with your route / url string.

Comment: Please update your question with any relevant information and avoid posting code in comments. 1 ) Posts can be deleted hiding your comments 2) its hard to read code in comments. Thanks!